# How to switch to https in the database? Hosting messed up and now Admin is text-only non-functional

Tags: admin-panel, https

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We just had an outage caused by the hosting company where all customers coming to our site were getting the "This is not safe" type of an Error message and where not actually seeing the Magento website.

When the site was down, I managed to login into the Admin panel and switched the unsecure URL and the secure URL to just http://www.oursite.com
The hosting company then fixed whatever problem it was and now the front end loads but when going to the URL for the Admin - it is text only. After I manage to login, it still shows as text only. I tried to modify things back to https in the text only version of the Admin panel but the "Save Config"button does not really work...Can I change the unsecure and secure URL back to https in the database? I have cPanel with phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit update the urls from database directly.
Goto table **core_config_data** and search for secure base url and unsecure base url then update those value column with your urls.

Hope this helps!